# IFrame Facebook App Bring User to the Top of the Page

Tags: javascript, iframe, facebook

I currently have an iframe for a facebook application and I am using  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(); to resize it properly. The problem is when a user scrolls down and clicks on one of the lower links, it does not a way to bring the user back to the top.

Is there a function or way of bring a user back to the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

The `href="#id"` links don't work in an iframe Facebook app, so the only way really is not to have your app depending on that. Of course, you could put a link to the same page so the user would actually reload the page and would be at the top, but I guess that's not an option. If you do manage to find a way to send the user to the top of the page without reloading tough, I would be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: Thats one of the reasons why I really dislike Facebook Development. Its a bunch of developers all looking for the same answer on how to solve a problem on a  platform that is constantly changing. If a solution comes up I will b sure to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a patch for this problem. 
I guess most of you guys use this patch to remove the scrolling bars : http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-remove-the-scrollbars-from-the-facebook-custom-tab-iframe/ so here is the patch :

1) Use the scrolling bars patch on the first page (the long one)

2) On the second page (the short one), put also the scrolling bars patch but :
2.1) Remove the FB.Canvas.setAutoResize()
2.2) Change the FB.Canvas.setSize() calls to FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 600, height: 670 }) where you can set your own width and height.

This doesn't bring the user to the top of the page, but it resizes the short page to its real height, which is a bit better.